# Should I recreate the model of a Ruby on Rails 3 Application to fit an expected REST Service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, json, rest

I'm creating a Web application which is simple enough, I am able to leverage a lot of standard Ruby on Rails 3 functionality (adding and removing model elements etc.).

Now I want to dish out a REST service, which returns a hierarchy of elements in one stream.

For example, in the model I have:

- ProductType, which defines which combinations of ComponentTypes are allowed. *Example:gift basket which is defined as having several Wine bottles and 3 pieces of fruit.*
- ComponentTypes. *Examples: fruit, wine bottles, etc.*
- Components: These are embodyments of ComponentTypes. *Examples: Sauvignon blanc, Apple, Pear, etc.*

Now I would like to provide a "menu" rest service, which displays a hierarchy of these. It should look something like this:

```
  "menu": [
{ "name":"Gift basket", "description":"some description", "price": 0, "isDefaultSelected": false, "isMultiselect":false ,"isContainer":true, "children":[
  { "name":"Wine", "description":"", "price": 0, "isDefaultSelected": false, "isMultiselect":false ,"isContainer":true, "children":[
    { "name":"Sauvignon Blanc", "description":"...", "price": 170, "isDefaultSelected": true, "isMultiselect":false, "isContainer":false },
    { "name":"Merlot", "description":"...", "price": 170, "isDefaultSelected": false, "isMultiselect":false ,"isContainer":false }
  ]
  },
  { "name":"Fruit", "description":"Fruits...", "price": 0, "isDefaultSelected": false, "isMultiselect":false ,"isContainer":true, "children":[
    { "name":"Apple", "description":"...", "price": 170, "isDefaultSelected": true, "isMultiselect":false ,"isContainer":false },
    { "name":"Pear", "description":"...", "price": 170, "isDefaultSelected": false, "isMultiselect":false ,"isContainer":false }
  ]
  }
]
}
```

From this, the client is to create a menu, where the items that have the property "isMultiselect" are checkboxes. Some attributes are arguably redundant (isMultiselect could simply be on a higher part of the hierarchy), but we have a requirement for all of the elements to be identical.

So my question is whether I should create a new model to represent the objects that I want to have in our REST service or whether I can render the objects that I have in a way that conforms to the above JSON Schema.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what 'menu' is. Is it just a list of ProductTypes? Are there multiple Menus?

As to the general question - yes, you should be able to use the existing resources defined for your JSON feed. If you need to customise the JSON feed (eg to include child resources), you can do so using the `respond_with` method:

```
respond_to :html, :json

def show
   @product_types = ProductType.all

   respond_with(@product_types, :include => [:component_types => :components])
end
```

Comment: There could be different menus in the future. Right now it's supposed to be a menu, from which the user can select products_types, configure them (by selecting the components to be part of this embodyment of a product type) and then add them to a shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/apeiros/awesome_nested_set) gem to see if you can represent your hierarchy that way. Basically you have to add 3 new columns to your existing model and you get all the standard tree support. Then you can add one or two simple routes to the related controller and you should be good to go.